# sp_describe_first_result_set fails at REVERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The `sp_describe_first_result_set` algorithm is essential to our ORM, but it fails to retrieve metadata when it detects a `REVERT` statement. Consider this snippet:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE spTest
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name sysname;
    
    EXECUTE AS CALLER;
    SELECT @name = USER_NAME();
    REVERT;

    SELECT 'Hello ' + @name AS Msg;
END

GO

EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'EXEC spTest', NULL, 0
```

The `sp_describe_first_result_set` fails with the following error message:

> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'REVERT;' in procedure 'spTest' does not support metadata discovery.

I understand how user context switching could create ambiguous results in some cases, but here I take great care to not cause ambiguous result sets, yet it doesn't help at all. Commenting out the `REVERT` statement actually solves the metadata issue, despite the `EXECUTE AS` — this seems rather backwards to me?

The procedure `spTest` above is obviously just made to demonstrate the issue, but the general pattern is something I often have to use in my procedures and this breaks the metadata. Is there a way around this? Is there a trick or any other way of accessing the **caller database principal** without `REVERT` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push down the code using REVERT into a separate proc, and call it in a wrapper proc using WITH RESULT SETS, eg

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE spTest_impl
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name sysname;
    
    EXECUTE AS CALLER;
    SELECT @name = USER_NAME();
    REVERT;

    SELECT 'Hello ' + @name AS Msg;
END

GO
create or alter procedure spTest
as
begin
  exec spTest_impl
  with result sets
  (
    (
      Msg nvarchar(200)
    )
  );
end
go

EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'EXEC spTest', NULL, 0
```

Comment: Good point, I had completely forgotten about WITH RESULT SETS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You *could* wrap the execute as stuff in dynamic SQL:

```sql
alter PROCEDURE spTest
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name sysname
    ,@sql nvarchar(max) = N'
    EXECUTE AS CALLER;
    SELECT @name = USER_NAME();
    REVERT;'
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@name sysname output',@name = @name output with result sets none;

    SELECT 'Hello ' + @name AS Msg;
END
```

This might lead to some bad side effects though, because of loss of permissions since dynamic SQL has own scope.

You might want to avoid this OWNER stuff and look into certificates etc, if you're using OWNER thing for permission related tasks.

Edit: `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` can perhaps be used for your needs as well?

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit dirty but a useful trick indeed. I try to stay away from the hassle of certificates and in my case the permissions translate badly to SQL permissions. I already had a look into ORIGINAL_LOGIN() some time ago, but it didn't work out well with contained databases.